# Open email folder in Thunderbird (v102.7.1) using the windows command line

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe, thunderbird

I'm trying to open a specific email folder in Thunderbird (v102.7.1), using the [command line arguments](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_-_Thunderbird).

I already found out that using `thunderbird.exe mid:<MESSAGE-ID>` will open the email with `<MESSAGE-ID>`.

Is there a way to open an email folder with a similar method or the command line in general?

I already tried:

- `thunderbird.exe mid:<FOLDER-LOCATION>`
- `thunderbird.exe mail:<FOLDER-LOCATION>`
- `thunderbird.exe inbox:<FOLDER-LOCATION>`
- `thunderbird.exe <FOLDER-LOCATION>`
- `thunderbird.exe label:<LABEL>`
- `thunderbird.exe -mail label:<LABEL>`
- `thunderbird.exe -mail -folder "mailbox://imap.<PROVIDER>.de/Inbox`
- `thunderbird.exe -mail <ACCOUNT NAME>/<NAMESPACE>/INBOX`

and various other things I don't remember anymore.

Comment: Welcome to the community. I'm not certain but I think this depends on where exactly the mail is. For example GMail doesn't have folders, but labels. If you have GMail, you could try something like thunderbird.exe label:<LABEL>. No guarantees tho' :-) These two came right up with google search - maybe they help? https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1148495 https://support.cdn.mozilla.net/en-US/questions/1374787

Comment: Sadly `thunderbird.exe label:<LABEL>` or any variation did not work. I'm affaid, the links did not provide any usefull information. Still a good idea tho.

Comment: Dang! I'd suggest you edit the question to add this. This is generally advisable so that the relevant info is directly available for the community members without digging it out from comments. As SE communities aren't discussion forums, I'd suggest checking the Help section to get a handle on how things work.